# why Junk characters at end?

Tags: c++, c

Here's example:

```
   main()
   {   
    // code to insert characters in between where letters repeat twice                                            
    char b[20];
    int l,i=0;   

      cin>>b;
      l=strlen(b);
      while(i<=l-1)
       {    if (b[i]==b[i+1]){          
                     for(int j=l-1;j>i;j--) 
                      b[j+1]=b[j];
                     b[i+1]='x';      
                     l++;
                } 
                i++;
       }
      puts(b); 
      getch();
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you overwritting the terminating null character in your string?

Comment: There is an opening brace `{` missing somewhere. Also it's `int main(void)` at least.

Comment: `why Junk characters at end?` is not a very good question.

Answer (score 5):

In `b[i+1]='x'`, the `\0` character is overwritten. It invokes undefined behavior when you print `b` with `puts`.

Comment: It doesn't access out of bounds.  It writes as far as the nul terminator for `b`, leading to undefined behaviour when it is later printed as a C-style string

Comment: @simonc; Missed that. Edited it.

Comment: If i use cout instead of puts, then?

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation is wrong.

```
if (b[i]==b[i+1])          
    for(int j=l-1;j>i;j--) 
    b[j+1]=b[j];
    b[i+1]='x';      
    l++;
}
```

is actually

```
if (b[i]==b[i+1])          
    for(int j=l-1;j>i;j--) 
        b[j+1]=b[j];
b[i+1]='x';      
l++;
}
```

Causing the last iteration of your `while` loop to overwrite the null terminator of `b` with `'x'`.  This then leads to undefined behaviour when you later call `puts(b)`.  In your case, it sounds like you're printing the uninitialised end of `b` and whatever follows it on the stack until you find a byte with value `0`.

You need to put braces `{}` around any multi-line conditions.  This type of bug also demonstrates why some teams insist on braces even for single line conditional statements

```
if (b[i]==b[i+1]) {
    for(int j=l-1;j>i;j--) {
        b[j+1]=b[j];
        b[i+1]='x';      
        l++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line    `while(i<=l-1)`

`l-1 = 19, if i = 19`, it will go into the loop

and

```
if (b[i]==b[i+1]) // the if statement here you are accessing b[20] which is out of bound and will lead to junk data / undefined behaviors
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(i<=l-1)
  ...
  b[i+1]='x';
```

With `i == l-1` you have that `b[l] = 'x'` so you are overwriting the `NUL` terminator, the end of the string is not there anymore. This causes its printing to doesn't end when it was before and going over junk characters past the end.

Answer (score 0):

cosidering your correctly-indented version is:

```
int main()   
    // code to insert characters in between where letters repeat twice 
{                                                                                  
    char b[20];
    int l,i=0;   

    cin>>b;
    l=strlen(b);
    while(i<=l-1)
    {    if (b[i]==b[i+1])                                                         
        for(int j=l-1;j>i;j--) 
            b[j+1]=b[j];
        b[i+1]='x';                                                                
        l++;
    }   
    i++;
}
puts(b); 
getch();
return 0;
}
```

I don't know how this compiles at all.  you need a `'\0'` at the end of your string though.